# Vim '=' does not work (CentOS 6)

Tags: vim, centos, vi, indentation

When i try **gg=G** or something like that i get error:

```
:.,$!indent
shell returned 127
4 lines filtered
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

On my Fedora destop it works fine. What's wrong?

config:

```
set autoindent
set tabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set number
set smartindent 
set showmatch
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can unset `equalprg` option:

```
set ep=
```

When `ep` is empty, vim will use the internal formatting function.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have the [indent](http://www.gnu.org/software/indent/) tool installed.

```
yum install indent
```